# how to keep two or more uicollectionview inside a tableviewcell?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios7, uicollectionview

Hi i am developing an iphone application that having a uitableview with uicollectionview,
how to do that with ios 7.

i am just trying to do as following for that i think i need a uicollectionview in a tableviewcell.
[image]

if anybody done like this please help me.

or if you have any other idea means please reply me.

this is what i have tried

```
   -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

static NSString *identifier = @"cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier                                                            forIndexPath:indexPath];

cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

Collectionclass *obj = [[Collectionclass alloc] init];

UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout=[[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];

UICollectionView *_collectionView=[[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame collectionViewLayout:layout];


[_collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];
[_collectionView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];


[_collectionView setDataSource:obj];
[_collectionView setDelegate:obj];

[cell addSubview:_collectionView];

    return cell;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try out this gr8 tutorial, even it has source code for your reference. It has worked for me.

http://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell

**Don'T blame, if Link expires.**